# Ubuntu disk space increase in an LVM group is not being reflected in the OS

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, lvm

I added some disks to my RAID configuration, taking it from 6TB to about 14TB. Increased the size of my Ubuntu server’s virtual machine disk to 12TB, and then used GParted to expand the partition from the original size to use all of the available 12TB.

But when I log into the server, it still says I’m 80% full. `df` doesn’t look wrong, but I can’t tell. Why hasn’t this changed? I did apply changes in GParted and it said it was successful.

Here’s my result in GParted after the changes and a reboot:

[image]

Here’s what I get when I log in and run `df`:

[image]

Any idea why the drive hasn’t appeared to be expanded?

**UPDATE:** After following [the directions in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/991261/167207), I made some progress: From an Ubuntu live CD, I found the mount point, unmounted it and scanned it with `e2fsck`, no problems there. When trying to resize it, I get **“The filesystem is already [xxxxxx] blocks long. Nothing to do!”** as the answer said I might. Not sure what else to do here. Is the fact this being an LVM have anything to do with it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using LVM so when you resized the partition, you just increased the size of the LVM *physical volume*. That space is then allocated to *logical volumes*.

If you want to increase the size of your existing logical volume to use that space, you use `lvresize`, in your case

```
sudo lvresize -L 100% /dev/mapper/gatlinburg--vg-root
```

…will expand it using all of the available space, and *then* you can expand the filesystem to use that space using:

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/gatlinburg--vg-root
```

You don’t have to unmount anything to do this.